# Bluemix: How to understand down time or low performance of the platform?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am currently using a free account, that will eventually move to a subscription later this month. I created a space in Sydney region and yesterday evening (Feb 02, 2016 India +5:30) the delivery pipeline became unresponsive. In the build stage, I had a maven build, Junit testing and Appscan static code scan.

Here are the details:

```
Job ​'Build'​ in Stage ​'Build from GitHub'​ #27 has ​​SUCCEEDED​
​Triggered by ​
​geekays​​
Started: 3/2/16 12:29:59 PM UTC
Duration: 1 minute 7 seconds
```

The build generally takes couple of seconds otherwise.

Job ​'UnitTest'​ in Stage ​'Build from GitHub'​ #27 has ​​SUCCEEDED​
​

```
Triggered by ​
​geekays​​
Started: 3/2/16 12:31:08 PM UTC
Duration: 1 minute 3 seconds
```

The UT generally takes less than 10 seconds.

```
geekays | java-web-service BOT
7:02 PM
Job ​
'Static Code Analysis'​ in Stage ​'Build from GitHub'​ #27 has ​​FAILED​
​
Triggered by ​
​geekays​​
Started: 3/2/16 12:32:21 PM UTC
Duration: 1 hour 0 minutes 5 seconds
```

The static code analysis actually timed out after the maximum permissible limit of 59 minutes.

It generally takes less than 10 minutes.

```
Job ​'Static Code Analysis'​ in Stage ​'Build from GitHub'​ #30 has ​​SUCCEEDED​
​Triggered by ​
​pipeline​​
Started: 3/3/16 9:06:38 AM UTC
Duration: 5 minutes 54 seconds
```

How to understand and respond in such a situation? Is Bluemix team aware of the down time? Or is there an environment provided for free accounts that are not maintained for a better SLA?

I am trying to understand this for being able to propose Bluemix as a solution to my clients.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking Bluemix team is alerted for all events with the platform and there is no difference between free and pay accounts in terms of environment.

Sudden events come either from monitoring systems or customers and are usually analyzed and resolved at the max priority.

Scheduled events like maintenance are announced at: 
https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status

Events related to specific services have to be sent by the customer to Bluemix Support that has SLA for taking in charge the tickets and let the service provider know about the problem.

Info about Bluemix Support SLA can be found in "SaaS Service handbook" in IBM Client Success Portal.

Comment: Actually, see the Bluemix Software as a Service information at the following URL: https://www-03.ibm.com/software/sla/sladb.nsf/sla/bm